# Mathematica gives complex coeffients when fitting polynomial

Tags: fitting, complex, polynomials

The problem is the following. I have two functions `A[m,x]` and `B[m,x]`. `m` is a variable, while `x` is a constant depending on other equations and parameters of the system. `A` is an integral which can only be evaluated numerically while `B` is a simple exponential function with the structure: `B[m,x] = A[0,x]*Exp[m/C]`, where C is a constant (and so is `A[0,x]` for a given `x`).

Now, I fit a 20 degree polynomial to `C = A[m,x]-B[m,x]`, in order to make Mathematica able to integrate `C`. This all appeared to work fine, until I suddenly discovered that for certain values of `x`, the polynomial fit has complex coefficients! This is very weird to me, because neither `A` nor `B` is complex. Could somebody please explain how the coefficients can become complex and how I can avoided it?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: My code looks like basically this:

```
A[m_,x_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-(Sqrt[v^2 + 2*m] - V)^2/2], {v, 0, Sqrt[2*(x - m)]}]

B[m_,x_] := A[0,x] * Exp[m/T]

Tbcomb := Table[{mprim, N[A[mprim,x] - B[mprim,x]]}, {mprim, 0, x, 0.01}]
Combfit := Fit[Tbcomb,
   {1, mprim, mprim^2, mprim^3, mprim^4, mprim^5, mprim^6, mprim^7, mprim^8,
       mprim^9, mprim^(10), mprim^(11), mprim^(12), mprim^(13), mprim^(14),
       mprim^(15), mprim^(16), mprim^(17), mprim^(18), mprim^(19),
       mprim^(20)},
   mprim
  ]
```

`T` and `V` are constants.

Comment: Are you fitting or solving? Please post a self-contained functioning code.

Comment: If you're getting values like `10^-16 I` then I would just `Chop` them as numerical artifacts. If they are sth like `0.5 I`, then one can make assumptions in e.g. `NonlinearModelFit`: `a\[Elem] Reals` or so.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @Feyre I am fitting. Code included!

Comment: `C` is a reserved Mathematica symbol, so you should not use it as a variable. In fact, it is good practice to use only use variables names beginning with lower case letters in the `Global` context.

Comment: Does your data contain complex numbers?

Comment: @corey979 well, the imaginary part vary between 10^(-12) and 10^(-1), so I am not sure I can neglect them.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you for the reminder! The functions in my real code is named things like "potentialdown" and so on, so I figured it would be simpler to just use A,B and C when posting here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MichaelE2 as far as I know, it doesn't.

Comment: "As far as I know..." -- Have you actually checked it?

Comment: `V` and `T` are symbolic or do they have a numerical value? `x` in `Tbcomb` needs to be set as well.

Comment: @MichaelE2 All my "data" comes from the functions A and B. These are describing densities and cannot take complex values. Therefore "as far as I know" there should be no complex data in the table.

Comment: @corey979 Yeah sorry about that, V and T are constants and we can view x as a constant as well.

Comment: I took `V = 0.1; T = 0.12; x = 1.;` and didn't get any complex coefficients.

Comment: Your second argument to `Fit` (list of functions) can be written more easily and succinctly as `mprim^Range[0,20]`

Comment: Well I can't check right now. Assuming there's no problem and there actually being no problem are two different things, especially when you are using numerical functions that include `Sqrt[]`.  An easy check is whether `Max@Abs@Im[Tbcomb]` is zero.  If it is, then one can safely rule out complex data as the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to lack of a set of parameters `V,T,x` in the **original question**, maybe I'll solve some synthetic problem to illustrate the approach:

Let's generate some data from a 20th order polynomial with dispersion:

```
poly[y_] := 1 + Sum[y^i, {i, 1, 20}]
data = Table[{x, poly[x] + RandomReal[0.1]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.01}];
plot1 = ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

The fit can be achieved with

```
f = Fit[data, Table[mprim^i, {i, 0, 20}], mprim]
```

> 1.03555 + 1.03503 mprim + 2.44307 mprim^2 - 2.50054 mprim^3 - 
>    36.73 mprim^4 + 61.9126 mprim^5 + 412.885 mprim^6 - 
>    468.637 mprim^7 - 2392.34 mprim^8 + 1986.07 mprim^9 + 
>    8283.7 mprim^10 - 5017.65 mprim^11 - 17939. mprim^12 + 
>    7804.28 mprim^13 + 24544.7 mprim^14 - 7313. mprim^15 - 
>    20585.9 mprim^16 + 3789.38 mprim^17 + 9657.23 mprim^18 - 
>    830.906 mprim^19 - 1937.02 mprim^20

We see that some of the coefficients are negative, but we want all of them to be positive.

Generate a polynomial `func` with coefficients `coeff` to be fitted:

```
var = Table[mprim^i, {i, 0, 20}];
coeff = Table[ToExpression["c" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 20}];
func = var.coeff;
```

and a list of conditions $c_i>0$:

```
cond = Table[coeff[[i]] > 0, {i, 1, Length@coeff}]
```

> {c0 > 0, c1 > 0, c2 > 0, c3 > 0, c4 > 0, c5 > 0, c6 > 0, c7 > 0, 
>    c8 > 0, c9 > 0, c10 > 0, c11 > 0, c12 > 0, c13 > 0, c14 > 0, c15 > 0,
>     c16 > 0, c17 > 0, c18 > 0, c19 > 0, c20 > 0}

Finally, one can use `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {func, cond}, coeff, mprim];
fit = Normal[nlm]
```

> 1.04529 + 0.972808 mprim + 1.0053 mprim^2 + 1.20048 mprim^3 + 
>    1.14997 mprim^4 + 0.0997689 mprim^5 + 0.688015 mprim^6 + 
>    2.91753 mprim^7 + 0.20959 mprim^8 + 0.095588 mprim^9 + 
>    2.86412 mprim^10 + 0.0702545 mprim^11 + 0.800427 mprim^12 + 
>    0.114977 mprim^13 + 0.520907 mprim^14 + 2.81414 mprim^15 + 
>    0.521147 mprim^16 + 1.69431 mprim^17 + 0.67438 mprim^18 + 
>    0.0238567 mprim^19 + 1.56535 mprim^20

All of the coefficients are positive.

[image]

**To tackle the problem of constraining the coefficients of `func` to be real**, in the definition of `cond` one ought to change "`>0`" into "`\[Element] Reals`", and in general it should work.